# Thymeleaf + Spring Boot: Error resolving template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this properties in the `application.properties`

```
server.contextPath=/pecador
server.port=5678
```

Running the through Eclipse I can access to the application and everything is fine

```
http://localhost:5678/pecador/login
```

But when I deploy the application in the server and running it with the command:

```
sudo nohup java -jar pecadorCloudApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar & /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
```

and I try  `http://149.152.231.117:5678/pecador/login`

I got this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/pecador/login/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

and unzipping the jar the template is there, under:

```
pecadorAPP.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/pecador/login/login.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're returning the view name with a leading slash(`/`). Just return `pecador/login/login` and it should work in both environments.

Check this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744